# How do you download or save a texture of a mesh

Tags: texturing

I was changing some textures for some meshes I was wondering if I could somehow either download the texture i made or save it to use it for other projects, is their any way how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about image textures you can save them in a folder: go in the *Image Editor* or *UV Editor > Image > Save As*:

[image]

If your image is packed, meaning it is part of your file and not in a folder (to pack an image, go into the *Image Editor* or *UV Editor* and *Image > Pack*, to pack all your images go into *File > External Data > Pack All Into .blend*), and you don't want it to be packed anymore you need to go into the *Image Editor* or *UV Editor > Image > Unpack* and either create a new folder or use the file's folder. To unpack all the images, go into *File > External Data > Unpack All Into Files*.

[image]

Now if you want to use this image in a new project, you'll find it in the folder where you've saved or unpacked it.

Another solution, that doesn't need any *Save As* or *Unpack* is to open your new project, go into *File > Append*, open the file that has the image texture you want, open the *Image* folder, and select the one you want:

[image]

Also there will be soon an *Asset Browser* window that will allow to visualize and import all sorts of datas. To make your image texture an asset, go in the *Outliner*, switch to *Blender File* mode, select the image, right click > *Mark Asset*:

[image]

If you open the *Asset Browser* window and in the left column select *Image & Sounds* you'll see your image:

[image]

Now open your new file, open the *Preferences > File Paths > Asset Libraries* > choose the folder(s) where you've saved the previous file(s). All the assets that have been saved in the files that are in this folder (or folders) will be available in the *Asset Browser > Default* mode:

[image]

Comment: ok thank you for the help

Comment: Consider  to mark answer as accepted 
https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: @Moonboots can you extend about "packed/unpack" texture?